# Processing: Number of Frames of Video

Tags: opencv, arraylist, processing, frames

1) Is there a way to know the number of the frames of a video after we load it but before playing it??

2) Also I want to take the first column from each frame. What I have thought is to read the whole video and store into an ArrayList every frame I read and then parse again the whole ArrayList and take the the first column from each frame. Is any more optimal way to do this?

Is any function in OpenCV that can help???

Comment: if you know the frame rate and the duration, is just a simple math...

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-get

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [VideoCapture](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture) class in OpenCV. Specifically the get function for retrieving video properties.

You can load each frame and store the first column like this:

```
//Video capture object
cv::VideoCapture cap;
cap.open("filename");

//Storage for video frames and columns
cv::Mat frame;
std::vector<cv::Mat> cols;

//Get each frame
while(true){
      //Load next frame
      cap >> frame;
      //If no frame, end of video
      if(!frame.data) break;

      //Store first column
      cv::Mat col;
      frame.col(0).copyTo(col);
      cols.push_back(col);
}
```